# Getting 400 Error when uploading image as formdata from flutter app (with dio) using Nodejs as backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, post, dio

I created a Nodejs backend with MongoDB as a database, in the frontend, I am using flutter. I want to store image in MongoDB, so I am sending post request from the flutter app using dio package. For authentication I am using middleware in the backend to authenticate web tokens, which is working fine. But after sending a post request and authenticating returning the right user, it is giving 400 error.

**authentication middleware**

```
const auth = async function(req,res,next){
    try {
        const token = (req.headers.authorization).split(' ')[1]
        const decoded_token = jwt.verify(token,'ankan12345')
        const user = await User.findOne({_id:decoded_token._id,"tokens.token":token})
        //console.log(user)
        if (!user){
            throw new Error()
        } 
        req.user = user
        req.token = token
        next()
        
    } catch(e){
        res.status(400).send("Please Authenticate")
    }
}
```

**User model**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        validate(val) {
            if (!validator.isEmail(val)) {
                throw new Error('Email invalid')
            }
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    dp:{
        type: Buffer
    },
    tokens: [{
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    }]

}, {
    timestamps: true
})
```

**Node js image upload endpoint**

```
const upload = multer({
    // For local storage uncomment this
    // dest:'./challenge_39/images',
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1000000000
    },
    fileFilter(req,file,cb) {        
        if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|PNG|png|jpeg)$/)){
            return cb(new Error("File type wrong"))
        }
        cb(undefined,true)

    }
})

// Auth and storing data binary to db
router.post('/upload',auth,upload.single('file_upload'),async (req,res)=>{
    
    //const modified = await sharp(req.file.buffer).resize({width:300,height:300}).toBuffer()
    // without modification 
    req.user.dp = req.file.buffer
    //req.user.dp = modified
    req.user.save()
    res.send()
},(error,req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("fdghf")
    res.status(400).send("error Upload a document")
})
```

**flutter dio request**

```
Future<dynamic> UploadDp(XFile img ) async {
    String filename = img.path.split('/').last;
    print(img.path);
    print(filename);
    try{
      dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MWJmMmMwNjg5MTVlOTdiNWMzZDAyNTAiLCJpYXQiOjE2Mzk5MTg3MzB9.4WCFxWtLc_wioexs0rq24bGKRG36oR0bzbMOgEjdRiA";
      FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
        "dp": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
          img.path,
          filename: filename,
            //contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg")
          //contentType: MediaType

        )
      });

      var response = await dio.post(
          'http://192.168.8.116:3000/upload',
        data: formData
      );
      return response;
    } catch(e){
      return e;
    }
  }
```

**Flutter button function**

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    XFile image;
    var image_picker = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if(image_picker!=null){
      setState(() {
        image = image_picker;
      });
    }

    apirepo.UploadDp(image).then((data)=>{
      print(data)
    });
  },
  child: Text(
      "Upload DP"
  )
)
```

Comment: "Getting a 400 error." If you check your code, _you are the one firing the error_ by rejecting invalid authentication. In `User.findOne()`, try passing `{_id:decoded_token._id, tokens: { token }}` instead of `{_id:decoded_token._id,"tokens.token":token }`.

Comment: I have a tokens array and elements are token and autogenerated id. In middleware I am getting user back. Uploading image works if I test my endpoint from postman. It doesn't work when I am sending from flutter

Comment: Oh, okay. What were your Postman configurations?

Comment: I have made fetching authtoken automatic by writing a small script, as of formdata I m passing key value pair of file_upload and sending file